# Is there one command to create or checkout an existing branch?

Tags: git

`git switch <branch>` allows me to move to an existing branch.

`git switch -c <branch>` allows me to create a new branch.

Is there a command where dependent on whether the branch already exists, it'll either create a new branch or check out the existing one?

Comment: I'm thinking no. When you create a new branch, you either specify a starting commit or you start from where you are currently. It's kind of weird to either move to another commit or create a branch pointing to whatever commit you happen to be on right now, without knowing which it will do. I'm curious what the use case would be even if it did exist? Note you can do this if you are willing to blow away the local branch and reset it to the remote. e.g. `git switch -C branch origin/branch` but that's not what you asked...

Comment: @TTT - I have a CI/CD pipeline where it's exporting Power Platform solution from a dev env and commiting to source control. When building the pipeline, the user specifies the branch they've like to export these changes into. I'd like to either create a new branch for them or commit the exported changes into an existing branch if it's part of a piece of work they're already working on

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in, but it is easy to define an alias or write a script:

```
if git show-ref --quiet "refs/heads/$branchname"; then
  git switch "$branchname";
else
  git switch -c "$branchname";
fi
```

or perhaps

```
git show-ref --quiet "refs/heads/$branchname" || create=-c;
git switch ${create:+"$create"} "$branchname"
```

Configuring it as alias:

```
git config --global alias.sw '!f() { if git show-ref --quiet "refs/heads/$1"; then git switch "$1"; else git switch -c "$1"; fi; }; f'
```

(or variant 2:)

```
git config --global alias.sw '!f() { git show-ref --quiet "refs/heads/$1" || create=-c; git switch ${create:+"$create"} "$1"; }; f'
```

Then use:

```
git sw branch-to-checkout-or-create
```

Comment: I'd use `git rev-parse --quiet --verify "refs/heads/$1"` as it's a proper Git plumbing command, but yes. (Also the rev-parse then needs to be redirected, which is a bit annoying - we don't want the hash ID...) Looks like show-ref becomes plumbing when used with `--verify` (i.e., this turns off fancy matching options), so there might be a lot of ways here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a command, but you can create an alias that will do it for you, in this example `git csw` (`git show-branch` will mark the current branch with `*` and will show that no branch has been reset):

```
$ git config alias.csw '!sh -c "git switch $1 || git switch -c $1"'
$ git show-branch
* [branch-a] b
 ! [master] h
--
*  [branch-a] b
*+ [master] h
$ git csw master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git show-branch
! [branch-a] b
 * [master] h
--
+  [branch-a] b
+* [master] h
$ git csw branch-a
Switched to branch 'branch-a'
$ git show-branch
* [branch-a] b
 ! [master] h
--
*  [branch-a] b
*+ [master] h
$ git csw branch-b
fatal: invalid reference: branch-b
Switched to a new branch 'branch-b'
$ git show-branch
! [branch-a] b
 * [branch-b] b
  ! [master] h
---
+*  [branch-a] b
+*+ [master] h
```